# not able to share one form control instance between 2 or more component instances

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I am having 2 phone number fields which should be in sync i.e. changing the 1st phone number fields should update the 2nd one and vice versa.

1. I had tried sharing one fromControl instance b/w those 2 phone number field components which didn't work.
   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ha16re?file=app/form-field-custom-control-example.html
2. I had also tried using ngModel that too didn't work.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <example-tel-input 
    placeholder="Phone number" 
    [formControl]="selectedTel"></example-tel-input>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <example-tel-input 
    placeholder="Phone number copy" 
    [formControl]="selectedTel"></example-tel-input>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
  selectedTel = new FormControl();

  constructor() {
    this.selectedTel.valueChanges.subscribe(newVal => {
      console.log('selected tel number is:', newVal);
    });
```

I am expecting that both the fields should be in sync.

Answer (score 0):

In your code replace **ngModel** with **[(ngModel)]="phoneNum"** 

You should use two way data binding.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <example-tel-input 
    placeholder="Phone number" 
    required
    name="phoneNumber" 
    [(ngModel)]="phoneNum"
    #selectedPhoneNumber="ngModel"></example-tel-input>
</mat-form-field>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<mat-form-field>
  <example-tel-input 
    placeholder="Phone number copy" 
    required 
    name="phoneNumber" 
    [(ngModel)]="phoneNum"
    #selectedPhoneNumber="ngModel"></example-tel-input>
</mat-form-field>

<h2>Current selection:</h2>
areas is: {{selectedPhoneNumber.value?.area}} <br/>
exchange is: {{selectedPhoneNumber.value?.exchange}} <br/>
subscriber is: {{selectedPhoneNumber.value?.subscriber}} <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change your subscribe to:

```
this.selectedTel.valueChanges.subscribe(newVal => {

       this.selectedTel.setValue(newVal, {emitEvent:false});
       console.log('selected tel number is:', newVal);
    });
```